# Is there any way to fix this error in VBNET?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm working on a discord bot.

I'm currently working on the login panel (the classic MySQL login way, with the `SELECT` statement.).

But I've started doing a thing called 2FA, and the way that it works, is the following: If the login was successful the application should set the `readytotwofactor` column (in MySQL) to `true`. If it's true, the discord bot generates a 10 letter code, which is appearing in the `twofactorcode` column. The BOT knows who to send the message to by watching the username entered in the TextBox when logging in. It looks for this in MySQL, and each column (registered username) is associated with a discord ID. Based on this, the BOT knows to whom to send the code that is checked in the MySQL column, the application can identify whether the code is correct or not. Once the code has been sent, the `readytotwofactor` column will automatically change to `false`, and the code I wrote should change the value in the `twofactorcode` column to `0`.

My problem, though, is that it doesn't work.

Here is the source code: (`Form3` is the login form, and `Form4` is the 2FA form.).

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("just the login stuff")

        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM karolyguilogin WHERE username=@username AND pass=@password", connection)

        command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text

        command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text

        Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `karolyguilogin` readytotwofactor SET readytotwofactor=@readytotwofactor WHERE username=@username", connection)

        Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)

        Dim table As New DataTable()

        Adapter.Fill(table)

        connection.Open()
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("írj be valamit!")
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("írj be valamit!")
            Me.Close()
        End If




        If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Helytelen felhasználónév, vagy jelszó!")


        Else


            command1.Parameters.Add("@readytotwofactor", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "true"


            MessageBox.Show("Hamarosan megkapod a 2FA kódod!")

            Me.Hide()

            Form4.Show()

            Me.Close()

            End If

        connection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form4

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("just the login stuff")

        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT twofactorcode FROM karolyguilogin WHERE twofactorcode = @twofactorcode <> NULL", connection)

        command.Parameters.Add("@twofactorcode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text

        connection.Open()
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("írj be valamit!")
            Me.Close()
        End If

        Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)

        Dim table As New DataTable()

        Adapter.Fill(table)

        If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then

            MessageBox.Show("A kódod helytelen, próbálkozz újra!")
        Else

            Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `karolyguilogin` twofactorcode SET twofactorcode=@twofactorcode WHERE twofactorcode <> NULL", connection)

            MessageBox.Show("A kódod helyes! Beléphetsz a felületre!")

          command1.Parameters.Add("@twofactorcode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "NULL"

            Me.Hide()
                Form3.Hide()
                Form1.Show()
                Me.Close()
                Form3.Close()

            End If

        connection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a useful question. Explain more clearly what it's supposed to do, and what it's doing wrong instead.

Comment: I second @Barmar, you need to [edit] the question and specifically describe your problem (error message, unexpected result, etc.). But one thing I can already tell you is that `<> NULL` won't do what you likely expect. Any operation in SQL where `NULL` is an operand is `NULL` and therefore not `true` (lookup "ternary logic in SQL"). If you want to check if something isn't `NULL` use `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @sticky bit, i also tried this with writing ```<> 0``` instead of ```<> NULL```, but that didn't help. There are no error codes. It's just doesn't work. It does nothing instead of writing the "readytotwofactor" column to true.

Comment: Read my comment again... Did I write `<> 0`? No. I wrote `IS NOT NULL`... But taking another closer look the column seems to be a `varchar` and you write the literal string `'NULL'` in it... For that you'd need to use `<> 'NULL'`. But having a literal string `'NULL'` instead of a true `NULL` has its own problems, so I wouldn't do that...

Comment: But anyway, "It's just doesn't work." isn't specific enough to really help you. So you really need to elaborate. And while you're at it, also add the `CREATE` statements of the tables.

Comment: ok then. i'll try to use 0 instead of the NULL's string format. As I was talking, the 0 is the empty state of the twofactorcode. If its 0, and the readyto2factor is set to true, it'll set itself to a randomly generated code. But only if it's set to 0. (or NULL before).  But thanks, this is a good starting point :D

Comment: I hope your connection string does not contain real user name and password etc.

Comment: @Marci You should read [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place, passwords should never be stored as plain text. I am hoping you have omitted the encryption code for brevity.

In ADO.net connections and commands need to be disposed, not just closed. A Using block will handle this for you even if there is an error.

Don't pull down the entire record. You only need to know if it exists. You don't need a `DataAdapter` to do this.

Do your validation outside the Using block before any database objects are created. Also, how to you expect the user to "Enter something" when you close the Form?

Use the same command for the second query, just change the `CommandText`. Note that we already have the `@username` parameter and the `@readytotwofactor` parameter is not needed because it can be hardcoded in the sql string.

Why hide the Form and then close it 2 lines later?

Perhaps your code doesn't work because you never execute the second command.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Validate first before the database code
    If TextBox1.Text = "" OrElse TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("írj be valamit!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim ReturnCount As Integer
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=sql11.freemysqlhosting.net;port=3306;username=sql11396664;password=eG1IbxNzLR;database=sql11396664"),
            command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM karolyguilogin WHERE username=@username AND pass=@password", connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        connection.Open()
        ReturnCount = CInt(command.ExecuteScalar())
        If ReturnCount = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Helytelen felhasználónév, vagy jelszó!")
        Else
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE `karolyguilogin` readytotwofactor SET readytotwofactor='true' WHERE username=@username"
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Hamarosan megkapod a 2FA kódod!")
            Form4.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Using 'Closes and disposes both the command and the connection
End Sub
```

I assume there is some sort of trigger in the database when `readytotwofactor` is set to true.

You realize your Update will set all records in the `karolyguilogin` table to the string "NULL" not just the the user attempting to log in. If this is a multiuser database this could cause a problem.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("írj be valamit!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim ReturnCount As Integer
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=sql11.freemysqlhosting.net;port=3306;username=sql11396664;password=eG1IbxNzLR;database=sql11396664"),
        command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM karolyguilogin WHERE twofactorcode = @twofactorcode", connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@twofactorcode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        connection.Open()
        ReturnCount = CInt(command.ExecuteScalar())
        If ReturnCount = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("A kódod helytelen, próbálkozz újra!")
        Else
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE `karolyguilogin` SET twofactorcode='NULL' WHERE twofactorcode <> 'NULL';"
            MessageBox.Show("A kódod helyes! Beléphetsz a felületre!")
            Form1.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Using 'Closes and disposes both the command and the connection
End Sub
```

I had fun translating the Hungarian message boxes so I could better understand your code.

Comment: thank you! You're my hero. I'm really begginner in programming (I'm 14yrs old). But I want to learn new things in the future! Thank you again, have a good day!